# pg_connect Fatal Error

Tags: php, postgresql, postgis

I am new to php and I am trying to connect to my postgis db via php on my webspace.
I am using the following code to achieve that:

```
<?php
$conn_string = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=dbname user=username password=pwd";
$dbconn4 = pg_connect($conn_string);
?>
```

Unfortunately this does not work and I am getting the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in /home/.sites/701/site1122/web/webgis/index.php on line 3
```

Do I need to install some kind of extensions? I don't have a php.ini file on my webspace, so I don't really know how to do that. I would be very happy for some suggestions.

Comment: you could check with `phpinfo()` whether there are extensions installed that can use PostgreSQL, see the documentation of [phpinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

Comment: Your PHP needs to have PostgreSQL support - but seriously, please use PDO anyway. The old-style `pg_connect` etc are deprecated.